# OpenGL: How to pause a shader work

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

How to pause a shader in frame in order to not influence to other render parts?

Comment: Are you using any framework for graphics cause, because as i know there is no such thing as pause a shader, first thing you compile the shader that you bind it wherever you need it, so basically you can skip it on some frames, but if you mean that you need to pause it by delaying it's execution than it's a complicated thing to achive and I can't imagine if it's even possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood you want to switch back to fixed pipeline functionality for rendering some other parts of the scene.

To unbind any shader currently in use issue `glUseProgam(0);`